# Background image stops working when uploaded to server (website)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to all this and I'm having a pretty annoying issue.

My site works fine when I open it from the folder on my PC but when I put my site online all the images stop working. I have uploaded the image folder and all the images I made sure.

I'm using bootstrap and bootstraps basic template.

Comment: any jsfiddle ? what image formats are you using ?

Comment: Probably your location of the images are not set right.

Answer (score 0):

The image file names had capitals in them and obviously the FTP server is case sensitive where as Windows is not.

Thanks though guys.